# how can i reduce the byte of the code bellow from 146 to 144 need help please

Tags: ubuntu, c, emacs, vi, typeset

How can i reduce the byte(memory) of the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/**
 * main - Entry Point
 * Return: Always 0 (success)
 */
int main(void)
{
        printf("Size of a char: %d byte(s)\n", sizeof(char));
        printf("Size of an int: %d byte(s)\n", sizeof(int));
        printf("Size of an long int: %d byte(s)\n", sizeof(long int));
        printf("Size of an long long int: %d byte(s)\n", sizeof(long long int));
        printf("Size of a float: %d byte(s)\n", sizeof(float));
        return (0);
}
```

to be 144 instead of 146 bytes?

Comment: The question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? Where do you see it's 146 bytes? Why do you need to reduce it to 144? Please [edit] your question and add more details to clarify this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a pure C programming question and not about Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a homework exercise...

By correcting two grammatical errors in the `printf` output strings, you would eliminate two characters, which might reduce the size of the compiled code by two bytes exactly.